# Creating a production ready Dockerfile for a Vite React app

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, vite

I have been using a Dockerfile to work on a Vite React TS app.

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /web

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

The app is complete and I am planning on deploying it to Fly.io, which uses Dockerfiles to create containers to run the app in. I am currently using `npm run dev` in my Dockerfile since I was working on development, but now I need to get my Dockerfile production ready.

What changes do I need to make to ensure that my Dockerfile runs the production ready commands for starting and running the app?